# CakePHP Pagination and Filter

Tags: sorting, cakephp, filter, pagination

I have pagination enabled for a table. Clicking on a page number creates a url with  /page:(page_number) appended.  Pagination works great for sorting and filtering.

The problem is:

- if I am on page 4
- then perform a search or filter

Results: The results will be displayed starting with page 4. I would like to start with page 1.

It is especially important if the search results in just one page.  Then I get an error.

The $query passed to BeforeFind, AfterFind,  BeforeFilter, and AfterFilter don't seem to indicate whether this is a pagination click or a search or filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always manually change the current page in your controller, with simple `$this->paginate['YourModel']['page'] = 1;`, but BEFORE you call `$this->paginate()`, of course. So in controller you just check if there is currently requested filter/search:

```
if ($filter = $this->request->query('filter')) {
    // apply the filter, most likely as a WHERE condition for pagination, not sure what is your case...

    // and force to display the first page
    $this->paginate['YourModel']['page'] = 1;
}
```

However, I see problem in deciding whether the filter/search is applied for first time or whether you just browse the search result to next pages. You could possibly store this info into session, but it doesn't feel too clever. Perhaps comparing if the requested and current page is the same, but it won't work when modifying the search term. So I think simplest way is to add hidden form field:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('page', array('value' => 1));
```

So when you search/filter it will automatically reset the page, without the controller code I wrote earlier. 
If you don't use classical form submit and do it via AJAX, you can attach the query parameter `page=1` and result is the same. Hope it helps you move forward

Comment: Great idea with the hidden page number in the form!  I ended up using a redirect to page 1 if results don't exist before I saw your answer.  Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Yep, the redirect is kind of brute force;)

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  I finally got it the easy way with a redirect in my controller.

For reasons unknown to me, this didn't work.  $movieStars is populated correctly, but something breaks it:

```
try {
        $movieStars = $this->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
        // If page results are not found
        // For example - we are on page and we search for something 
        // Results returned for page 7 - but only two results

        // Not sure why this doesn't work - $movieStars are properly set and code continues
        $request = $this->request;
        $theseParams = $this->request->params;
        $pageFromParams = $theseParams['named']['page'];
        $passedArgs = $this->passedArgs;
        $pageFromArgs = $passedArgs['page'];

        $breakme = true;

        $this->request->params['named']['page'] = '1';
        $this->passedArgs['page'] = '1';

        $requestHere = $this->request->here;
        $requestUrl = $this->request->url;

        $newHere = preg_replace('/page:(\d+)/', 'page:1', $requestHere);
        $newUrl = preg_replace('/page:(\d+)/', 'page:1', $requestUrl);

        $this->request->here = $newHere;
        $this->request->url = $newUrl;

        $movieStars = $this->paginate();
    }

    $this->set(compact('movieStars'));
```

But this little redirect trick did it.

```
try {
        $movieStars = $this->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {

        // finally found easy solution if paginate throws error - redirect to page one
        $requestUrl = $this->request->url;
        $newUrl = preg_replace('/page:(\d+)/', 'page:1', $requestUrl);
        $redirectUrl = preg_replace('/movie_stars\//', '', $newUrl);
        $this->redirect($redirectUrl);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set form action url instead of cake automatic url . like this : $this->Form->create('ModelName',array('url' => array('action' => 'index'));

because cakephp auto generates the form url and it also appendsthe current query string in the url.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to put the url of the form in the view then it is always submitted to a clean url and the page parameter disappears